# Need help looping through an xml file with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my first time working with ajax in any way so please bear with me.

In my program I have a drop down boxes that will dynamically pull zip codes, counties and cities depending on the state that is selected. So far the counties are working correctly, but the zip codes and cities are only showing the first record on my xml sheet.

The xml looks something like this:

```
<states>
   <counties>
     <county>
       <countyid>id#1</countyid>
       <countyname>nassau</countyname>
     </county>
   </counties>
   <zipcodes>
     <zip>10109</zip>
   </zipcodes>
   <cities>
     <city>New York</city>
   <cities>
</states>
```

Now, the javascript that loops through the counties section looks like this:

```
target1.options[0] = new Option("Select County", "null");
for (var i = 0; i < xmlCounties.length; i++) {
target1.options[target1.options.length] = new Option(xmlCounties[i].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue, xmlCounties[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue, false, (matched == xmlCounties[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
```

}

That works just fine, but for the cities and zip codes they don't, which both look like this and are identical to the above example:

```
target2.options[0] = new Option("Select Zipcode", "null");
for (var i = 0; i < xmlZips.length; i++) {target2.options[target2.options.length] = new Option(xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue, xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue, false, (matched == xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue));
}
```

They both pull data from the xml, but only the first record. Any ideas on how to get this fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Which javascript libraries (if any) are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any libraries, just straight up javascript.

Answer (score 0):

county is 2 level deep.. zip and city are only one level deep. Thats the reason. Try this

```
target2.options[0] = new Option("Select Zipcode", "null");
for (var i = 0; i < xmlZips.length; i++) {target2.options[target2.options.length] = new Option(xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue, xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue, false, (matched == xmlZips[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's it because I am getting the first record in my xml for zip code and city, it's just not looping through and pulling all of the results. I tried your suggestion and it only pulled a null value. I do appreciate the suggestion, thanks.